# On a morphism of schemes defined by sheaves of algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let,$(X, \mathcal O_X)$ be a scheme and $\mathcal B$ be a quasicoherent  sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$ algebra.Then for any $U =spec(A)$ affine open of $X$ the map $\mathcal O_X(U) \to \mathcal B(U)$ induces a morphism of schemes given by $\pi_U: Spec(\mathcal B(U)) \to U$

I want to prove that it's an affine morphism

My attempt: Let's cover $U =SpecA$ by affine opens $D(f) =SpecA_f$.Let's denote the image of an arbitrarily fixed $f$ as  $\tilde f$ under the map $\mathcal O_X(U) \to \mathcal B(U)$.Then we know that inverse image of each such $D(f)$ under $\pi_U$ will be $\mathcal (B(SpecA))_\tilde{f}$,which is affine as $\mathcal B$ is quasicoherent.Thus we are done.

Doubt: It seems from this we can conclude any scheme morphism from $SpecR$ to $SpecS$ is also affine which is not true.

Please correct me if the proof is wrong.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: What is your definition of affine? If I'm not mistaken, it *is* true that if $X$ and $Y$ are affine schemes, then any morphism of schemes $\pi \colon X \to Y$ is necessarily affine. This is true because one can check whether a morphism is affine on a suitable affine open cover of the target, and the trivial cover by $Y$ itself has $\pi^{-1}(Y) = X$ affine! See (e.g.) Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry", Prop 7.3.4.

Comment: @Alex Wertheim, you are correct, any morphism between $2$ affine schemes is necessarily an affine morphism.I realize that my question was trivial.